# Переместить элемент на 10px

Tags: javascript, css

Необходимо сместить  элемент на 10px пикселей вправо, использую:

```
var elem =  document.getElementById('elem');
elem.style.left = getComputedStyle(elem).left + 1 + 'px';
```

Но getComputedStyle выводит значение с "px", нужно как-то чтобы только цифру выводило.

Comment: погуглите parseInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
elem.style.left = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(elem).left) + 10) + 'px';
```